# Common domain authentication for multiple home PCs

Tags: server, samba, authentication

I'm a software developer doing some baby first steps in linux administration, but now with the virus situation it's clear to me more than ever, that I need to set up my home PCs such that there will be common domain authentication across all of them. I know Active Directory is the standard for that kind of thing but I want to avoid using Windows for anything and actually even get rid of it from the computers that run it today. What are the services I would need to set up so that I could have the following on any computer that I attach to mydomain.com :

1. logon credentials and authentication in a common place, I don't want to set up the same user accounts on every computer
2. /home/myuser should be an smb network mount
3. I'm a little bit on the fence here, but maybe I would like 2 to be available also while outside my home LAN, through a VPN. Not sure here though.

I'm probably going to use Ubuntu for the server, hopefully the shiny new 20.04 when it's out, and very much likely also for the client machines. Alternatively I'm considering pure Debian for the server, but I don't see much of a difference as far server capabilities are concerned.

I'm not looking for someone to type in the commands I need, but I would very much appreciate pointers in the right directions - what will I need to set up and what's a good read on the subject. I imagine it will be quite some work, especially that I have other things I will need to run on that server, but that's ok.

Comment: Considering the new and LTS release *focal fossa* makes sense, however if you check https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: I appreciate Your answer, thanks. In the aspects that interest me here in this question I don't think 19.10 will be that much different though. My main reason for waiting for 20.04 is the announced 5 year LTS period which is awesome.